# user generated html storage in database: json, html, xml, or other solution?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, json

In an application where users is creating and editing many html fragments,
 There are several options for storing the data:

sample data:
array of sections, each with a title and array of html 'chunks.'

```
content: {sections: [ {title: 'section 1 ' htmlunits: ['<div..>' , '<div..>'] }  ]   }
```

1.store it a json in database.
problem: escape characters will enter the JSON when the object is stringified. 
         html decode function in server may not decode it back to original state,
         resulting in a malformed string.

2.store it as one html string.

```
<div id="content">

    <ul class="section" data-title="section 1">
    <li class="htmlunit"> '<div..>' </li>
    li class="htmlunit"> '<div..>' </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
```

problem: seems messy, more characters than xml.

3.store it as xml:

```
(seems like SO is censoring the xml....)

<xml>
<content>
<section title="section 1">
<htmlunit> '<div..>' </htmlunit>
<htmlunit> '<div..>' </htmlunit>
</section>
<content>
</xml>
```

- #3 seems like the best option.

Perhaps I am overlooking some other options, or an advantage/drawback of one of the above.Any recommendations are much appreciated.

Comment: "seems messy, more characters than xml"...really??? Not that it's an important metric, but your XML will almost certainly take more characters to represent than just the plain html.  If you're just storing and retrieving it from a database, who cares if it's `messy`?

Comment: I mean that xml is a bit more semantic, because instead of a bunch of div, ul, li elements whose meaning comes from their class/id, the tag name itself describes the object. less chars in xml because less attributes. Currently I am using the html version and was wondering if its justified to switch to xml.  As you have affirmed its not a big enough difference to warrant a change.